# Run WCF Service Library when .exe in debug is ran

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf

When I run my WPF that uses my WCF Service Library through visual studio I get a WCF Service Host startup at the same time with my service starting my WCF Service Library, however when I click on the exe for my WPF in the debug folder it doesn't startup is there anyway to make it start in code as the following code I have believed would work doesn't.

```
try
{
    host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1), new Uri("http://" + System.Net.Dns.GetHostName() + ":8733/DatabaseTransferWcfServiceLibaryMethod/Service1/"));
    host.Open();
}catch(AddressAlreadyInUseException)
{
}
```

I'm trying not to use service references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay the error was way away from where I thought it was the error was it was running on my user interface thread so needed to add.

```
[ServiceBehavior( UseSynchronizationContext = false)]
```

If anyone else has this problem i hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert at this, but perhaps you're missing the binding. Here is the simplest example I can create of hosting and consuming a WCF service in code (you'll need to add references to System, System.Runtime.Serializaton, and System.ServiceModel, but otherwise, this code is complete).

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

   class Program
   {

      static void Main(string[] args)
      {

         // Create the host on a single class
         using
         (  ServiceHost host
          = new ServiceHost
            (  typeof(MyService)
            ,  new Uri("http://localhost:1234/MyService/MyService")
            )
         ){

            // That single class could include multiple interfaces to
            //  different services, each must be added here
            host.AddServiceEndpoint
            (  typeof(IMyService)
            ,  new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.None)
               // Each service can have it's own URL, but if blank use the
               //  default above
            ,  ""
            );
            // Open the host so it can be consumed
            host.Open();

            // Consume the service (this cuold be in another executable)
            using
            (  ChannelFactory<IMyService> channel
               = new ChannelFactory<IMyService>
               (  new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.None)
               ,  "http://localhost:1234/MyService/MyService"
               )
            ){ IMyService myService = channel.CreateChannel();
               Console.WriteLine(myService.GetValue());
            }

            // Clean up
            host.Close();

         }


      }

   }

   [ServiceContract]
   public interface IMyService
   {  [OperationContract] int GetValue();
   }

   public class MyService : IMyService
   {  public int GetValue()
      {  return 5;
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: I have added in the binding but it freezes up and becomes not responsive at the equivalent 'Console.WriteLine(myService.GetValue());'

Comment: @ZoomVirus Does it freeze in the example code I sent? When it freezes at your equivalent code, is in an infinite freeze, or does it time-out. Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: It times out when I run debug in visual studio but if I click wait for it to respond it never times out. And the example code you put does the same.

Comment: @ZoomVirus Sorry, I don't know enough about this to respond. I just know the code I sent works for me. If you can't create your own host, do you have IIS? You could you host your WCF library there.

Comment: Unfortunately using IIS doesn't fit my requirements, but thank you for the tempt to help.